# JSON- How to read json file in java

Tags: java

I have a custom portlet with one dropdown item. Additionally i have a products.json file.

**My Requirement**

The dropdown shows the products and when the user clicks on a product, the corresponding details are fetched from the json file and displayed.

How do i do that ?

```
{
"products" : [  
  {  
     "id":"prod_1001",
     "name":" iPhone 6",
     "type":"Mobile",
     "asset_tag":"<asset_tag>",
     "serial_no":"34238941",
     "cost_center":"",
     "cpu_count":"2",
     "cpu_socket":"8",
     "cpu_name":"Intel",
     "cpu_type":"core",
     "cpu_speed_mhz":"2200",
     "disk_gb":"64",
     "ram_mb":"2048",
     "first_discoverd_date":"",
     "recent_discovery_date":"",
     "service_start_date":"",
     "warrent_expiry_date":"",
     "ip_address":"10.10.10.1",
     "lease_contract":"",
     "lease_start_date":"",
     "lease_end_date":"",
     "location":"India",
     "sku":"IPHONE-6",
     "cost":"500",
     "currency":"$",
     "cpu":"",
     "power_supply":"12v",
     "hard_drive":"1",
     "memory":[  
        {  
           "memory_type":"ram",
           "sku":"RAM-4GB"
        },
        {  
           "memory_type":"Internal",
           "sku":"INTERNAL-128GB"
        }
     ],
     "warranty_expiration":"",
     "gps_location":"India",
     "network_domain":"domain",
     "network_segment":"segment",
     "group":"Product",
     "company":"Apple"
  },
  {  
     "id":"prod_1005",
     "name":"Nokia",
     "type":"Mobile",
     "asset_tag":"<asset_tag>",
     "serial_no":"34238941",
     "cost_center":"",
     "cpu_count":"2",
     "cpu_socket":"8",
     "cpu_name":"Intel",
     "cpu_type":"core",
     "cpu_speed_mhz":"2200",
     "disk_gb":"32",
     "ram_mb":"2048",
     "first_discoverd_date":"",
     "recent_discovery_date":"",
     "service_start_date":"",
     "warrent_expiry_date":"",
     "ip_address":"10.10.10.1",
     "lease_contract":"",
     "lease_start_date":"",
     "lease_end_date":"",
     "location":"India",
     "sku":"IPHONE-6",
     "cost":"500",
     "currency":"$",
     "cpu":"",
     "power_supply":"12v",
     "hard_drive":"1",
     "memory":[  
        {  
           "memory_type":"ram",
           "sku":"RAM-4GB"
        },
        {  
           "memory_type":"Internal",
           "sku":"INTERNAL-128GB"
        }
     ],
     "warranty_expiration":"",
     "gps_location":"India",
     "network_domain":"domain",
     "network_segment":"segment",
     "group":"Product",
     "company":"Microsoft"
  },
```

Comment: Use a json library such as Jackson. What is your technology stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a number of JSON libraries like the json maven library available [here](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/json/JSONObject.html)

You can use them to convert JSON strings to JSONObjects and use accessor methods defined in those objects to parse through the JSON Data

Answer (score 0):

Also try Gson [libray](https://github.com/google/gson)

You have 2 choices:

- create a Product javabean by yourself and get result as a list
- get result list as a generic map

`List<Product> list = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Product>)(){}.getType());`

or

```
Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
```